# How can I measure the flicker frequency of a light source with my phone?

Tags: sensor, calculations, physics, theory

I have a Hue light and want to measure the flicker frequency (due to the PWM) without buying an expensive photometer. Is it possible, to calculate it with such an Image, by counting the bars from the rolling shutter effect?

[image]

I've already done some work to gather further information:

- Captured by a Samsung Galaxy S23, which got an Isocell GW3 image
  sensor
- Sensor area 8.160x6.144 pixels à 1µm
- 27 FPS @ 50 MP (but I think thats irrelevant for picture taking)
- ShutterType: Electronic rolling and global reset

[image]

*GRR (Global Reset Release Shutter)- diagram - https://docs.baslerweb.com/electronic-shutter-types*

So theoretically, together with the given exposure time (i think it was 1/20000s here) and the information on how fast the sensor reads the individual rows, it should somehow be possible to determine the frequency with the top image, shouldn't it? Unfortunately, I can't find the Temporal Offset tRow [µs] () for this sensor anywhere.

PS: I'm a little confused, how *rolling and global release shutter* could create such an Image, shouldn't the black bars have a brightness gradient and not be completely black? That's more like a classical Rolling shutter effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the sensor readout speed you only need to count the bright lines to get cycles/ms which can be easily converted to cycles/sec or Hz.

> PS: I'm a little confused, how rolling and global release shutter could create such an Image, shouldn't the black bars have a brightness gradient and not be completely black? That's more like a classical Rolling shutter effect.

That is a rolling shutter effect. Global reset can only be used when flash is used; i.e. when the camera is set to flash. And the reset only affects the lines that received exposure; the light lines, not the black ones.

Comment: So I can just say: 20000/16 = 1250Hz? (Then I've made it much more complicated than it is lol)

Comment: But it's strange. With a shutter speed of 1/20000 I can count 16 bright bars. With a shutter speed of 12000 I can also count 16 bright bars but they appear thinner and the dark ones get bigger. That would result in a very different frequency

Comment: https://ibb.co/qR96jSh

Comment: Is it simply because my phone is too imprecise? Because the "dark" ones aren't really dark anymore at 1/12000s; at 1/20000s, it's much more discreet. Even at 1/500s, I still count 16 lines (https://ibb.co/ZmZRFPQ)...

Should I just take the highest measurable value (1250Hz) and say it's somewhere above 1250Hz, or is it somewhere below that?

Comment: @iwab, I messed up my answer (edited now) The speed you need to know is the maximum sensor readout speed, which will be the same for all shutter speeds faster than that.

Comment: aaah thanks! Hmm now I need to find out the readout speed of that photo sensor of the main camera in my s23 :/ can't find any public information about it. Is something between 0,017s and 0,02s reasonable? I've read somewhere, that most hue smart lamps flicker at around 1kHz. 16÷0,017s ≈ 941Hz ≈ 1kHz

Comment: I mean, the max FPS for the S23 Cam is 240FPS, doesn't that mean that the sensor must have a read out speed of at least 1/240s?

Comment: I would say so... the fastest sensor rolling readout speed I am aware of is ~ .004s. and the slowest I know of is .08s...whereas somewhere around .03s is much more common. Being that the phone sensor is very small, it is probable to be towards the faster end.

Comment: The 240fps limit should be the point where the sensor is at 100% duty cycle (each row immediately begins exposure for next frame as soon as read out).

Comment: When I hit record (with 120 FPS in FHD) and look at a single frame, I can now count 11 bars. I guess the s23 doesn't have the same readout speed for every mode (to safe energy, when high speed isn't really required?) So now I can say for sure: 11/(1/120) = 1320Hz that my lamp flickers with ≥1320Hz?

Comment: For FHD/ 60 FPS it still shows 11 bars (so the sensor still reads out faster than it have to with at least 1/120s). In super slow mo I've read it shoots with 240fps: There I've count 6 bars (so only one half, which makes sense) 6/(1/240) ≈ 11/(1/120). Oh man that feels like Reverse Engineering non public Samsung photo sensor specifications 

Comment: Looks like you've got it down... sensor readout speed seems to be 1/120. The high speed slow motion mode is probably line skipping.

Comment: And even learned something new, wow thanks :D "Line skipping" is leaving out every xth row in the sensor to read out faster (for slow mo) and that's also the reason the overall video quality in slow mo isn't that good?

Comment: Yes. If it is line skipping and the resolution remains the same, then it is interpolating  (digitally creating) the skipped lines.

Comment: I still have one last question  if I take a normal photo with 12M resolution, I get back my 16 bars. We found out that in video mode the readout speed is 1/120s and slow mo 1/240s. Now to make it equal, 16/(1/x) ≈ 11/(1/120) ≈ 6/(1/240) the readout speed x must equal around 1/82s. Is that possible?  Why would the normal camera mode run with such an odd readout speed and wouldn't a higher one like 1/120s or 1/240s be better if an object moves for example?

Comment: Cell phone cameras do all sorts of weird things without necessarily telling you... it's not uncommon for them to actually record multiple images and combine them as one. Or it might be pixel binning (combining pixels) for reduced noise at lower resolution. But yes, a higher readout speed is better if there is motion.